# React Lightbox Component doesn't open

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I admit I am very new to React and still getting my head around things, but I am using the react-lightbox-component to display images in a grid and that works just fine but the onClick event doesn't do anything then it calls the toggleLightBox function.

I know the onClick is working as I tested it against a simple console.log, what am I missing to be able to display the image in a lightbox when clicked?

```
const App = ({ compile }) => (
  <div style={{margin: 20}}>
    <header style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
        <h1><Words animate>Art</Words></h1>
    </header>
    <body>
      <h3>Android</h3>
    </body>
    <Lightbox
        images={androidimages}
        renderImageFunc={(idx, image, toggleLightbox, width, height) => {
            return (
                <img
                  key={idx}
                  src={image.src}
                  style={{width: '150px', height: '200px', margin: '20px'}}
                  onClick={
                    toggleLightbox.bind(null, idx)
                  }
                />
            )
          }
        }
    />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: can you provide an example in the sandbox?

Comment: A link to `react-lightbox-component` github or npm page can help

Comment: react-lightbox-component has already been imported and IS working, it's just the toggleLightbox function I can't seem to get to work:

import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';

Comment: The component can be found here: https://github.com/jfcaiceo/react-lightbox-component